# .NET Authentication framework equivalent to Devise for Ruby

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, devise

I'm making an app in Xamarin that requires login using local user accounts (not using any third party OAuth such as Google or Facebook) and I had previously worked with Devise for a Ruby on Rails app, and it's perfect for what I need here.  I need to have a local (as in not hosted on a third party server) user database, email confirmation, forgot password, etc, and Devise was able to handle all of this gracefully. I have looked at Xamarin.Auth but it only mentions OAuth.  Is there anything for C#/.NET/Xamarin that is functionally equivalent to Devise? I haven't found anything on Google, and the closest SO question I could find was this [Authentication engine for ASP.Net MVC like Devise for Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070134/authentication-engine-for-asp-net-mvc-like-devise-for-rails) but it's both old and it doesn't really provide any good solutions, and I was wondering if something may have changed in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're in the C# / NET stack, I would recommend [Identity Server 4](https://github.com/IdentityServer). It is an OIDC provider, you can also use it as classic authentication service using username/password.
You are looking for the [Resource Owner password flow](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/resource_owner.html), which requires invoking the [Token Endpoint](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/endpoints/token.html) of this service.

While I wouldn't suggest rolling your own authentication, sometimes there's a need for it. In that case, choosing a mature and standardized solution is the best way to move forward.
Identity Server 4 is an OIDC compliant, highly configurable and scalable .NET option.